# Copying data from a table to another with spring boot jpa using custom query

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am newbie in spring boot. I am developing an application with spring boot jpa such that when a curriculum of courses is set, a front-end will be provided for approval. On click on approve button, the set courses will be copied from courses table to course_confirm table but i get this error: "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}"" even when I used the native SQL query without the "WHERE id >1" clause. Followings are the codes:

1. Both the courses bean class and course_confirm class (tables) have the same fields as following:

   ```java
   @Entity
   @table(name = "course_confirm")
   public class CourseCh extends AuditModel{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;

   @NotEmpty(message = "course code required")
   @Column(name = "course_code")
   private String code;

   @NotEmpty(message = "Course title required")
   @Column(name = "course_title")
   private String title;

   @NotEmpty(message = "Department required")
   @Column(name = "dept_id")
   private String deptid;

   @NotEmpty(message = "Credit units required")
   @Column(name = "credit_unit")
   private String creditunit;

   @Column(name = "semester")
   private String semester;

   @Column(name = "course_type")
   private String type;

   @NotEmpty(message = "Pass mark required")
   @Column(name = "pass_mark")
   private String passmark;

   @NotEmpty(message = "Session required")
   @Column(name = "session")
   private String session;

   @Column(name = "first_prerequisite")
   private String prerequisite1;

   @Column(name = "second_preriquisite")
   private String prerequisite2;

   @Column(name = "joint_prerequisite")
   private String jointprerequisite;
   //The getters, setters and tostring are left out for brevity
   ```
2. Repository layer:

```java
    @Repository
    public interface MoveCourseRepository extends CrudRepository<CourseCh, Long>{
        
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT into course_confirm (course_code, credit_unit, dept_id, joint_prerequisite, pass_mark,"
                + "first_prerequisite, second_preriquisite, semester, session, course_title, course_type, "
                + "created_at, updated_at) SELECT course_code, credit_unit, dept_id, joint_prerequisite, "
                + "pass_mark, first_prerequisite, second_preriquisite, semester, session, course_title, "
                + "course_type, created_at, updated_at from courses WHERE id > 1")
        List<CourseCh> moveCourseConfirm(long id);
```

3. Service layer:

```java
    @Override public List<CourseCh> saveCourseConfirm(long id) { return moveCourseRepository.moveCourseConfirm(id); }
```

4. Controller layer:

```java
    @GetMapping("/updateCurriculum/{id}")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
        
            // get employee from the service
            CourseCh course = courseChService.findCourseChById(id);
        
            // set employee as a model attribute to pre-populate the form
            model.addAttribute("course", course);
            return "course/update_course";
        }
```

I will really appreciate if anyone could help me mitigate aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

When using `@Query` in `JpaRepository` you have to use `@Param` for query parameters in repository method and add `:` in front of parameter name in query.

So you should try

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT into course_confirm (course_code, credit_unit, dept_id, joint_prerequisite, pass_mark,"
                + "first_prerequisite, second_preriquisite, semester, session, course_title, course_type, "
                + "created_at, updated_at) SELECT course_code, credit_unit, dept_id, joint_prerequisite, "
                + "pass_mark, first_prerequisite, second_preriquisite, semester, session, course_title, "
                + "course_type, created_at, updated_at from courses WHERE :id > 1")
        List<CourseCh> moveCourseConfirm(@Param("id") long id);
```